# useState hook on select not same when changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a for loop in my options inside a select, everytime I change a state, it changes to the last  selected value while the e.target.value is the current value, I want it to have a dispatch inside that's why I didnt do it inline with the onChange on my select element.

```
  const [blk, setBlk] = useState(1);

  const getBlks = () => {
    let blks = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 33; i++) {
      blks.push(
        <option key={i} value={i}>
          {i}
        </option>
      );
    }
    return blks;
  };

  const blkHandler = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setBlk(e.target.value);
    console.log(blk);
  };
```

for example, when I change my select from 1 to 3, the e.target.value changes to 3 while the blk is 1. Don't know why it changes to this behavior.

Comment: where do you call blkHandler ?

Answer (score 0):

> make sure you have put `blkHandler()` in the select element for eg.

---

`<select value={blk} onChange={blkHandler}> render options.... </select>`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your console.log ...

from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

You can use the useEffect hook to test if your state has changed in a functionnal component like

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(blk)
},[blk])
```